# Receiving name of the element as an object

Tags: javascript, object, element

This is my JavaScript code:

```
<script>
function change(name){
    var element = document.all.name.value;
}
</script>
```

It returns an error. How to pass to the function the element's name in order to change its value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a quick fix:

```
var element = document.all[name].value;
```

But keep in mind this gets the value, not the element itself. To get the element, then change the value, do:

```
var element = document.all[name];
element.value = 'whee';
```

Also, you should consider using another way to access the elements instead of `document.all`. Look into using IDs instead of names with the `document.getElementById()` function. See this [JavaScript best practices](http://www.javascripttoolbox.com/bestpractices/#all) list.

As [Peter Bailey points out in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587407/receiving-name-of-the-element-as-an-object/2587459#2587459), many HTML elements can have the same name. This is one reason why `document.getElementById()` is preferable: element IDs are unique (in valid HTML, of course).

Comment: Good answer.  I would recommend using ID.  Then you can do document.getElementById(id);  Much more reliable

Comment: @Zoidberg: Yep, was integrating that into my answer as you commented :-)

Answer (score 2):

If by "name" you mean "name attribute", you have to understand that names are not unique to an HTML document.  They need context.

Although you can use `document.all` - that is non-standard and only works in IE.  You'll be better off using a more cross-browser friendly mechanism.

Typically, name attributes will belong to elements in a form, such as `<input/>` and `<select>` elements. The names of these elements are exposed as properties of the `<form>`'s `elements` property in the DOM.

If you can get access to the form's DOM object, then you can access its elements' DOM objects too.

An example

```
<form id="foo">
  <input type="text" name="test" />
</form>

<span onclick="change( 'foo', 'test' );">Change Value</span>

<script type="text/javascript">

function change( formId, elementName )
{
  // Get the form's DOM object
  var f = document.getElementById( formId );

  // Get the element's DOM object
  var element = f.elements[elementName];

  // Modify the element's value property
  element.value = 'Hello World';

  // Note, the above 3 lines can be refactored to this
  // document.getElementById( formId ).elements[elementName].value = 'Hello World';
}

</script>
```

Comment: `document.all` also works in Opera, but I agree it still shouldn't be used if at all possible (which is almost always the case).